# Command RuleScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode10.1

[image]Command RuleScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Answer (score 0):

In my case, then first delete derive data then I connect an actual iphone not simulator and run the app once on it, It solved the problem. But connect iphone firstly, then choose it from the menu of simulators, then press run button.
The problem will solve too.